# Substitute for getch(), gotoxy(), delay(), clrscr()

Tags: c++, c

I have some old program source code that I wrote for Turbo C compiler. I made changes to them and want to recompile them in newer compilers for Linux and Windows. So please tell me what are the best alternative functions to

> getch(), delay() / sleep (), clrscr(),
> gotoxy()

for C and C++.

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at the [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library, for Unix compatible systems.

Answer (score 9):

For Windows systems:

Best is to compile the program as a console application for windows.

You can directly use the Windows API for console windows and console output.
Take a look at the MSDN: [Windows Console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Here are possible replacements for the given functions:

- getch(): use _getch() from conio.h
- delay()/sleep(): use the windows Sleep() function
- clrscr(): write your own clrscr() function by using FillConsoleOutputCharacter() and FillConsoleOutputAttribute()
- gotoxy(): use SetConsoleCursorPosition()

Comment: `system("cls")` should do the job for `clrscr`. :)

Answer (score 2):

On Unix-like systems you can use VT100 escape codes for replacing clrscr() and gotoxy(). clrscr():

```
std::cout << "\033[2J" << std::flush;
```

See http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm for gotoxy() and more.

Answer (score -1):

1. To replace `clrscr()`, you can use ***`system("cls");`*** (available with `#include<stdlib.h>`).
2. To replace `getch()`, you can use ***`system("pause");`*** (also available with `#include<stdlib.h>`).

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO ! Please also add substitutes candidates for gotoxy() and delay().

Comment: `system("pause")` is a *very* limited substitution for `getch`. And OP wants Linux compatibility too, and both are windows-only...