# subsititue of getchar and clrscr() in c for linux

Tags: c, linux

I am working on Ubuntu these days. When I compiled my C program using gcc, it is giving the error `conio.h` doesn't exists. 
I want to use `clrscr()` and `getch()` function.
Can you please tell me the substitute of this header file in linux.

Comment: Check out the [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GNU/Linux replacements for Turbo C functions \`clrscr\` and \`cprintf\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079943/gnu-linux-replacements-for-turbo-c-functions-clrscr-and-cprintf)

Answer (score 3):

The `getch()` function can be found in `curses.h` (library "curses"). The same library offers functions to clear the screen. Check out these links:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch

http://linux.die.net/man/3/erase

Comment: I believe the curses `getch()` function can be used only after calling `initscr()`, which takes control of the (text) screen.

Answer (score 3):

`system("clear");` can be used in **linux** instead of `clrscr();`

Answer (score 2):

```
# include <curses.h>

       int erase(void);
       int werase(WINDOW *win);
       int clear(void);
       int wclear(WINDOW *win);
       int clrtobot(void);
       int wclrtobot(WINDOW *win);
       int clrtoeol(void);
       int wclrtoeol(WINDOW *win);

DESCRIPTION
       The erase and werase routines copy blanks to every position in
       the window, clearing the screen.
```

I'm guessing this question was repeatedly downvoted because it implies a poor understanding of basic C language features and/or that OP is simply copying/pasting code into editor/IDE.

Similarly, just use `system("exit");` within your code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
system("clear"); //clears the screen
}
```

Checking the man-pages shows:

```
SYSTEM(3)                                 Linux Programmer's Manual   SYSTEM(3)

NAME
       system - execute a shell command

SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdlib.h>

       int system(const char *command);

DESCRIPTION
       system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c 
command, and returns after the command has been completed.  
During execution of the command, SIGCHLD will be blocked, and SIGINT
and SIGQUIT will be ignored.
```

---

It could also be the case that this question is a possible duplicate of the following:

- [How to implement getch() function of C in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276546/how-to-implement-getch-function-of-c-in-linux)
- [Why can't I find <conio.h> on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux)
- [GNU/Linux replacements for Turbo C functions `clrscr` and `cprintf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079943/gnu-linux-replacements-for-turbo-c-functions-clrscr-and-cprintf?rq=1)
- [Function clrscr in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226329/function-clrscr-in-c-and-c)
- ["UNDEFINED REFRENCE TO clrscr();"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750450/undefined-refrence-to-clrscr?rq=1)
- [Substitute for getch(), gotoxy(), delay(), clrscr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693130/substitute-for-getch-gotoxy-delay-clrscr?rq=1)
- [What is Equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux?rq=1)

Finally, take a look at the following for more details and examples:

- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/scanw.html#GETCHCLASS
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=549023

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you didn't try googling.

There are no direct alternatives.

This blog post: http://wesley.vidiqatch.org/code-snippets/alternative-for-getch-and-getche-on-linux/ provides you with alternatives for `getch()` and `getche()`

Alternatively you can use libncurses to do what you want: http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/linux/message/29221

Comment: I am trying for curses.h and it too is not found on my ubantu o.s

Comment: Have you tried locating it in the repositories? If you don't know how to do that, try askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

curses.h is an alternative for conio.h.
install build-essentials and install libncurses5-dev.

Then you can work with that functions.
[http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=880601][1]

Answer (score 0):

I was tinkering around with some codes; after i installed ncurses, I inserted these codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

main ()
{

system ("clear");
getchar ();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do it through C code instead system call.

```
void clrscr(void) {
  fprintf(stdout, "\033[2J\033[0;0f");
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

I found it long time ago and I've checked it on raspbian successfully.

And also:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
  printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B, y, x);
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In G++ Compiler, we use `system("clear")` function defined in `stdlib.h` header File

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
  std::cout<<"Hello Aliens:";
  system("clear");
}
```