# Error:ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main() {
    void message();
    message();
    getch();
    clrscr();
    return 0;
}

void message() {
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    gets(name);
//  gotoxy(25,4);
    printf("%s has a bright future",name);

}
```

Above is the code that I am trying to execute. But the error does nnot allows it and get stuck at clrscr().
I have the conio.h file in the system but still it does not accepts it.
How should I come across this error?
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750450/undefined-refrence-to-clrscr

Comment: My goodness -- using a 20+ year old compiler?  Unlike fine wine, a compiler doesn't age well.  That code isn't even valid C++ since `main` doesn't have a return type.

Comment: Please never use `gets`. The 20+ year old compiler is no excuse. `gets` doesn't even exist anymore, in C or C++.

Comment: Hey Chris. Thank you for the quick response. What could be used in place of gets?

Comment: I know its a silly program but I need know. I am new to this.

Comment: @PunitPanjwani You can simply use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @PunitPanjwani, In C, you can use `fgets` for the same effect (except it stores the newline in the buffer). In C++, `std::string` is much easier.

Comment: You can solve your problem by simply avoiding this weird fascination some beginners seem to have with clearing the screen at every opportunity.

Comment: Kelm & Chris...Your suggestions worked...Thank you guys....