# why does my clrscr function isn't working

Tags: c

I'm a new C programming learner. I'm writing a code by including `stdio.h` and `conio.h` but if I write `clrscr();` inside my code, it isn't working. If I remove the part `clrscr();` it's working. Why??

Here's the source code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    printf("A tab \tis used in this line.");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["UNDEFINED REFRENCE TO clrscr();"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750450/undefined-refrence-to-clrscr)

Comment: "it isn't working" is not a very helpful description of a problem. How isn't it working? When does the problem occur? Specifically what do you type at the command line, and what is the compiler output?