# C programming: Substitute for conio.h? (cursor.h doesn't work either)

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile this code but my IDE (vmware virtual machine) doesn't recognize the header file conio.h. Does anyone know a way around this?
This code reads in the values of three characters from the keyboard and prints the sum.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 

void main() 
{ 
int a,b,c,d,e; 
clrscr(); 

printf("\n Enter the three numbers:"); 
scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c); 

d=a+b+c; 


printf("|n The sum is %d", d); 
getch(); 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823904/subsititue-of-getchar-and-clrscr-in-c-for-linux

Comment: "my IDE (vmware virtual machine)" - what's your ***actual*** IDE, and operating system? conio.h is Windows-specific.

Comment: `<conio.h>` is windows specific - removing the `clrscr()` and `getch()` calls is indeed probably the simplest fix.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448944/c-non-blocking-keyboard-input/448982#448982

Comment: My system is a virtual machine in Linux. It has a C compiler.

Comment: Your fix worked! Thank you.