# How to use old commands in new compilers?

Tags: c++

I am making a record entry system in C++. In this system, I need to use commands like gotoxy,clrscr,sound,nosound,etc. I work in Code::Blocks IDE and use a GNU GCC compiler. For the gotoxy command, I even downloaded the header file but still it does not work. Can anyone give me the code or the duplicate of these functions.Thanks!

Comment: what is your compiler ( conio.h does not work in the newer compilers )

Comment: My compiler is Codeblocks IDE as I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: I'm asking compiler ( like MinGW or gcc ). CodeBlocks is the IDE, not the compiler. Read this [Difference between an IDE and Compiler](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/o8TbqMoL/)

Comment: FYI, those are not "commands" but "functions". They are not provided by any halfway-modern OS or compiler either, they rather come from old DOS times. Your best bet for creating a text UI is to use a so-called "curses" library. Suggestion: Your knowledge of C++ seems to be very small or outdated, so pick up a contemporary tutorial, it will answer many of your questions.

Comment: "Why many commands not working properly...?" is not an appropriate question. What do you expect us to answer: "The company doesn't test its product well enough"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `<conio.h>` does not work on modern compilers . It only works on old IDE's ones like TurboC++ and DevC++ ( They are very old, TurboC++ was used in the 20th century, no one hardly uses it anymore ). So, in short, it won't work unless you get an old compiler ( which is not a good idea ).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But is there a duplicate for the function gotoxy?

Comment: [Substitute for getch(), gotoxy(), delay(), clrscr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693130/substitute-for-getch-gotoxy-delay-clrscr)

Answer (score 1):

## <conio.h> is ancient.

`<conio.h>` was commonly used in Turbo C, to manipulate the console input/output. This was prominent in the old DOS age, where most of the things were *command-line*.

As for now, `<conio.h>` is **not** supported in `gcc`.